# Is there a PHP equivalent of Ruby's WebMock?

Tags: php, laravel, mocking, phpunit

I've inherited a Laravel project with some tests that are making external network requests. I'm looking for a library to mock these out like [WebMock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock). There are couple things I like in particular about WebMock:

1. Intuitive interface for stubbing out requests by URL and specifying a response.
2. Blocks all external requests by default.

Is there anything on the PHP side like this? I have experience with PHPUnit and mocking. I've tinkered with [Mockery](https://github.com/mockery/mockery). I'm looking for something focused on this particular issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Heve you tried `Codeception`? It's a very nice test framework for PHP

https://codeception.com/

Codeception is 100% compatible with laravel - http://codeception.com/for/laravel

I'm not aware of any plugin that intercept http requests in the code to block them, but you can mock http request using this plugin http://github.com/mcustiel/phiremock-codeception-extension

Comment: I've used it with a WordPress project before with mixed results. My impression was it wrapped a nice interface around PHPUnit, but I'm not sure if that is accurate. How well would you say it addresses the two points raised in my question? Is it compatible with Laravel?

Comment: Codeception is 100% compatible with laravel - https://codeception.com/for/laravel - however I'm not aware of any plugin that intercept http requests in the code to block them, but you can mock http request using this plugin https://github.com/mcustiel/phiremock-codeception-extension

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to [Phiremock](https://github.com/mcustiel/phiremock). It's not exactly what I had in mind, but it's in the ballpark. It also led me to some other options listed [here on phppackages.org](https://phppackages.org/s/http%20mock). If you want to add Phiremock to your answer, I'd think it worth an upvote at the very least.

Comment: I've seen what WebMock can do and it's actually cool. Edited my post, cheers @TomatFFI